# What are the maximum size for a seed in php?

Tags: php, random

What is the maximum input value for a seed in PHP? Is it 2^32? 2^64? No limit?

I cannot seem to find an answer in PHP documentation.

Comment: Wouldn't be no limit... I'd guess 2^63-1 (i.e. PHP_INT_MAX). But that's unbacked speculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`php_srand`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/af6c11c5f060870d052a2b765dc634d9e47d0f18/ext/standard/rand.c) takes a `long`, and it calls one of `srandom`, `srand48`, or `srand` (depending upon compilation defines).

It casts the seed value to an `int` in the case of `srandom/srand`, but passes the full `long`-typed value through to [`srand48`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/srand48) - so then it comes down to implementation of the system/stdlib random functions (and actual size of `int`).

---

Also, considering that `mt_srand` takes a `uint32`, I'd say it's reliable to expect 32-bit seeds to be considered distinct (even if they start the same sequence). A 64-bit seed is the upper value limit (even if the entire seed is not used), but is only realizable in a 64-bit version of PHP.

Any non-integer value (i.e. float) supplied as a seed will be coerced to an integer. The actual `php_srand` C function is only called after coercing the supplied PHP value to a long in the wrapper.

Comment: Note: [`mt_srand`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/af6c11c5f060870d052a2b765dc634d9e47d0f18/ext/standard/rand.c#L196) may also be relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getrandmax()` to determine the maximum value. ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getrandmax.php

Comment: That's not technically the *seed value*.

Comment: the seed's an int. rand() returns an int. so technically it's returning what you can input (max) as a seed.

Answer (score 0):

`srand` takes an `int` which I assume is a 32-bit number on 32-bit machines according to the docs. and 64 on 64-bit machines.